# How to post data using autocomplete when item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery autocomplete box that is linked to remote source. When something is selected I want it to post off the ID of that item.

This is what I have so far but no luck with posting the data

```
$( "#artist1" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
            var artist1 = ui.item.id;
            var id = $("#id").val();


            $.post('writeToDB.php', { id:id, artist1:artist1});

            }
        });
```

This code works on other elements but not when I put it in autocomplete. Where could I be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `select` event, and put your logic there.
For more details take a look at [jQueryUI's official demo of autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

### Code examples

```
// Supply a callback function to handle the select event as an init option.
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});

// Bind to the select event by type: autocompleteselect.
$( ".selector" ).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
$( "#artist1" ).autocomplete({

        select: function(event, ui) 
        {
            var artist1 = ui.item.id;
            var id = $("#id").val();
        },

        source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url :"search.php" ,
            data : "id="+id+"&artist="+artist1,
            dataType: "json",
            type : "POST",
            success : function(data)
            {
                yourdata
            })

        response(yourdata);
            }
        });
        },
        minLength: 2
        });
```

this is an example you have to make some changes in this.